# menustrip items disappeared but still avaliable on my designer.cs

Tags: c#, winforms, items, menustrip

```
   private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
        this.richTextBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
        this.menuStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip();
        this.okumaHızıToolStripMenuItem1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.toolStripMenuItem2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.toolStripMenuItem3 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.toolStripMenuItem4 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.toolStripMenuItem5 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.toolStripMenuItem6 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.toolStripMenuItem7 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.toolStripMenuItem8 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.toolStripMenuItem9 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.toolStripMenuItem10 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.toolStripMenuItem11 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.toolStripMenuItem12 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.toolStripMenuItem13 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.toolStripMenuItem14 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.toolStripMenuItem15 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.okunacakMetinToolStripMenuItem1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.kırmızıBaşlıklıKızToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.kaşağıToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.satrançStefanZweigToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.bölüm1ToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.bölüm2ToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.bölüm3ToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.metroPanel3 = new MetroFramework.Controls.MetroPanel();
        this.button2 = new FontAwesome.Sharp.IconButton();
        this.buttondurdur = new FontAwesome.Sharp.IconButton();
        this.button1 = new FontAwesome.Sharp.IconButton();
        this.metroPanel1 = new MetroFramework.Controls.MetroPanel();
        this.metroPanel2 = new MetroFramework.Controls.MetroPanel();
        this.ıconButton8 = new FontAwesome.Sharp.IconButton();
        this.vahşetinÇağrısıToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.bölüm1ToolStripMenuItem1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.bölüm2ToolStripMenuItem1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.bölüm3ToolStripMenuItem1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.bölüm4ToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.bölüm1ToolStripMenuItem2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.bölüm2ToolStripMenuItem2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.bölüm3ToolStripMenuItem2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.metroPanel3.SuspendLayout();
        this.metroPanel2.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // timer1
        // 
        this.timer1.Interval = 1000;
        this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        // 
        // richTextBox1
        // 
        this.richTextBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonFace;
        this.richTextBox1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
        this.richTextBox1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.IBeam;
        this.richTextBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 15.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
        this.richTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(412, 245);
        this.richTextBox1.Name = "richTextBox1";
        this.richTextBox1.ReadOnly = true;
        this.richTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(620, 649);
        this.richTextBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.richTextBox1.TabStop = false;
        this.richTextBox1.Text = "";
        // 
        // menuStrip1
        // 
        this.menuStrip1.AutoSize = false;
        this.menuStrip1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(51)))), ((int)(((byte)(51)))), ((int)(((byte)(56)))));
        this.menuStrip1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 15.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
        this.menuStrip1.GripStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripGripStyle.Visible;
        this.menuStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.menuStrip1.Name = "menuStrip1";
        this.menuStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(598, 42);
        this.menuStrip1.Stretch = false;
        this.menuStrip1.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // okumaHızıToolStripMenuItem1
        // 
        this.okumaHızıToolStripMenuItem1.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
        this.toolStripMenuItem2,
        this.toolStripMenuItem3,
        this.toolStripMenuItem4,
        this.toolStripMenuItem5,
        this.toolStripMenuItem6,
        this.toolStripMenuItem7,
        this.toolStripMenuItem8,
        this.toolStripMenuItem9,
        this.toolStripMenuItem10,
        this.toolStripMenuItem11,
        this.toolStripMenuItem12,
        this.toolStripMenuItem13,
        this.toolStripMenuItem14,
        this.toolStripMenuItem15});
        this.okumaHızıToolStripMenuItem1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
        this.okumaHızıToolStripMenuItem1.Name = "okumaHızıToolStripMenuItem1";
        this.okumaHızıToolStripMenuItem1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(122, 38);
        this.okumaHızıToolStripMenuItem1.Text = "Okuma Hızı";
        // 
        // toolStripMenuItem2    (Missing item)
        // 
        this.toolStripMenuItem2.Name = "toolStripMenuItem2";
        this.toolStripMenuItem2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(103, 22);
        this.toolStripMenuItem2.Text = "130-";
        this.toolStripMenuItem2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.toolStripMenuItem2_Click);
        // 
        // toolStripMenuItem3   
        // 
        this.toolStripMenuItem3.Name = "toolStripMenuItem3";
        this.toolStripMenuItem3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(103, 22);
        this.toolStripMenuItem3.Text = "150-";
        this.toolStripMenuItem3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.toolStripMenuItem3_Click);
        // 
        // toolStripMenuItem4       
        // 
        this.toolStripMenuItem4.Name = "toolStripMenuItem4";
        this.toolStripMenuItem4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(103, 22);
        this.toolStripMenuItem4.Text = "170-";
        this.toolStripMenuItem4.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.toolStripMenuItem4_Click);
        // 
        // toolStripMenuItem5      
        // 
        this.toolStripMenuItem5.Name = "toolStripMenuItem5";
        this.toolStripMenuItem5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(103, 22);
        this.toolStripMenuItem5.Text = "190-";
        this.toolStripMenuItem5.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.toolStripMenuItem5_Click);
        // 
        // toolStripMenuItem6
        // 
        this.toolStripMenuItem6.Name = "toolStripMenuItem6";
        this.toolStripMenuItem6.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(103, 22);
        this.toolStripMenuItem6.Text = "230-";
        this.toolStripMenuItem6.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.toolStripMenuItem6_Click);
        // 
        // toolStripMenuItem7
        // 
        this.toolStripMenuItem7.Name = "toolStripMenuItem7";
        this.toolStripMenuItem7.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(103, 22);
        this.toolStripMenuItem7.Text = "280-";
        this.toolStripMenuItem7.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.toolStripMenuItem7_Click);
        // 
        // toolStripMenuItem8
        // 
        this.toolStripMenuItem8.Name = "toolStripMenuItem8";
        this.toolStripMenuItem8.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(103, 22);
        this.toolStripMenuItem8.Text = "330-";
        this.toolStripMenuItem8.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.toolStripMenuItem8_Click);
        // 
        // toolStripMenuItem9
        // 
        this.toolStripMenuItem9.Name = "toolStripMenuItem9";
        this.toolStripMenuItem9.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(103, 22);
        this.toolStripMenuItem9.Text = "380-";
        this.toolStripMenuItem9.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.toolStripMenuItem9_Click);
        // 
        // toolStripMenuItem10
        // 
        this.toolStripMenuItem10.Name = "toolStripMenuItem10";
        this.toolStripMenuItem10.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(103, 22);
        this.toolStripMenuItem10.Text = "470-";
        this.toolStripMenuItem10.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.toolStripMenuItem10_Click);
        // 
        // toolStripMenuItem11
        // 
        this.toolStripMenuItem11.Name = "toolStripMenuItem11";
        this.toolStripMenuItem11.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(103, 22);
        this.toolStripMenuItem11.Text = "600-";
        this.toolStripMenuItem11.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.toolStripMenuItem11_Click);
        // 
        // toolStripMenuItem12
        // 
        this.toolStripMenuItem12.Name = "toolStripMenuItem12";
        this.toolStripMenuItem12.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(103, 22);
        this.toolStripMenuItem12.Text = "700-";
        this.toolStripMenuItem12.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.toolStripMenuItem12_Click);
        // 
        // toolStripMenuItem13
        // 
        this.toolStripMenuItem13.Name = "toolStripMenuItem13";
        this.toolStripMenuItem13.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(103, 22);
        this.toolStripMenuItem13.Text = "850-";
        this.toolStripMenuItem13.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.toolStripMenuItem13_Click);
        // 
        // toolStripMenuItem14
        // 
        this.toolStripMenuItem14.Name = "toolStripMenuItem14";
        this.toolStripMenuItem14.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(103, 22);
        this.toolStripMenuItem14.Text = "1050-";
        this.toolStripMenuItem14.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.toolStripMenuItem14_Click);
        // 
        // toolStripMenuItem15
        // 
        this.toolStripMenuItem15.Name = "toolStripMenuItem15";
        this.toolStripMenuItem15.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(103, 22);
        this.toolStripMenuItem15.Text = "1400-";
        this.toolStripMenuItem15.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.toolStripMenuItem15_Click);
```

while I was designing my winform the items in the menustrip disappeared suddenly and then I checked the designer.cs they are still there but I can't reach them on my form. The missing ones are those toolStripMenuItem1 between toolStripMenuItem15. It looks like they lack location and other properties but I m not sure about the problem.

My form now has menustrip but it lacks items it is empty.

Comment: Those MenuItems are added as the DropDownItems of the `okumaHızıToolStripMenuItem1` ToolStripMenuItem which, it appears, is not added to anything (orphaned, possibly, you're not showing the whole Designer file).

Comment: then why I can't see okumaHızıToolStripMenuItem1  ?

Comment: Just written above: `okumaHızıToolStripMenuItem1` appears to be orphaned. It should *probably* belong to `menuStrip1`, but it's not added to it. Not shown here, anyway.

Comment: Can you please show the full designer file?

Comment: this is the full designer.cs of related form ısn't it ?